# Trouble with oracle sql in java

Tags: java, oracle

Hi I am currently testing out a large PreparedStatement, but I seemed to be stuck in the rut. At the moment I have an error "Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 243"

Here is my code for reference:

```
//Create a query string
    String sqlQuery=null;
    sqlQuery="insert into tbl_email_template(template_code,template_file_name,template_file,status,"
            + "system,type,email_from,email_subject,email_reply_to,email_content,uploaded_by,"
            + "dcreate,dmodify) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    System.out.println("Total:"+rsmd.getColumnCount());
    Clob clob = con.createClob();

    File file = new File("template.msg");
    MapiMessage msg = MapiMessage.fromFile(file.toString());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    clob.setString(1, msg.getBody());

    Date date = new Date(1,2,3);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    pstmt.setString(1, "haha");
    pstmt.setString(2, file.getName());
    pstmt.setBlob(3, fis,file.length());
    pstmt.setString(4, "A");
    pstmt.setString(5, "MRS");
    pstmt.setString(6, "BK");
    pstmt.setString(7, "haha@hoho.hk");
    pstmt.setString(8, msg.getSubject());
    pstmt.setString(9, "harhar@hehe.hk");
    pstmt.setClob(10, clob);
    pstmt.setString(11, "Generic User123");
    pstmt.setDate(12,date);
    pstmt.setDate(13,date);
    pstmt.execute();

    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: show your full error

Comment: maybe use [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ; should be removed:

```
sqlQuery="insert into tbl_email_template(template_code,template_file_name,template_file,status,"
        + "system,type,email_from,email_subject,email_reply_to,email_content,uploaded_by,"
        + "dcreate,dmodify) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
```

should read:

```
sqlQuery="insert into tbl_email_template(template_code,template_file_name,template_file,status,"
        + "system,type,email_from,email_subject,email_reply_to,email_content,uploaded_by,"
        + "dcreate,dmodify) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

For the rest: I can not count the characters as given from your error, so your error might or might not be solved by this....

Comment: are you sure - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941539/is-the-semicolon-necessary-in-sql

Comment: Yes, look at the comments at the accepted answer there regarding the multiple statements and semi column

Comment: what multiple statements has this OP got? One single insert

Comment: Still the ; works disruptive in this. That is not said that it is the error observed. So the user will have to test and see if it resolves (user seems to be offline).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914269/preparestatement-appears-to-be-stripping-semicolon -- basically it would appear that your answer (at best) not useful or (at worst) is wrong

Comment: My experience: Add a ; in the jdbc.execute leads to issues.

Comment: For once removing a ; actually works and I can run my query

Comment: That's strange, maybe an Oracle driver problem?  For completeness can you post you full error